# Is it possible to obfuscate javascript after page load

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, obfuscation

I asked similar question before but I didn't find solution that works.
I return model to the view with list if items.
Than on razor view I user `@:` razor syntax to add markers to google map.
The problem is when someone inspects page code he can see this:

```
...
addMarker('aaa', 1, 44.010052, 20.914279, '', 'aaa', 'test', map, '', 'aaa');
                    addMarker('aaa', 1, 44.016009, 20.91445, '', 'aaa', 'test', map, '', 'aaa');
...
```

I am trying to find solution to not display this.
Maybe it has something with using `@:`

```
foreach (var item in Model.Rents)
                {   
                    @:addMarker('@item.prop', @item.prop, @item.Latitude, @item.Longitude, '', '@item.prop', '', map, '', '@item.prop');

                }
```

Comment: No, unless you're going to request (async) some JS file on page-load, and have the server obfuscate that file on-the-fly on each request. But why would you want to do that?

Comment: If it's on the client-side, the client can see it. No way around it.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem because I don't want that somebody easily get those data and populate it's database with it :( for example I can't go to foursquare site and see coordinates in code behind.

Comment: @1110: obfuscating the code is just an adding an obstacle to see the data, but it's still there. If you don't want the client to see the code, either use AJAX, or consider using a compiled language...

Comment: Is it possible to add pins to google map with c# for example?

Comment: You would have to generate the map as an image on the server side.. you're trying hard to do something that shouldn't need doing. The maps are client side.. therefore they need client side things to run. The best you'll get is losing the script in a messy tangle of spaghetti references to the actual script..